# XML file from ZIP Archive is incomplete in C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, zip

I've work with large XML Files (~1000000 lines, 34mb) that are stored in a ZIP archive. The XML file is used at runtime to store and load app settings and measurements. The gets loadeted with this function:

```
 public static void LoadFile(string path, string name)
    {
        using (var file = File.OpenRead(path))
        {
            
            
            using (var zip = new ZipArchive(file, ZipArchiveMode.Read))
            {
                var foundConfigurationFile = zip.Entries.First(x => x.FullName == ConfigurationFileName);

                using (var stream = new StreamReader(foundConfigurationFile.Open()))
                {
                    var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ProjectConfiguration));
                    var newObject = xmlSerializer.Deserialize(stream);
                    CurrentConfiguration = null;
                    CurrentConfiguration = newObject as ProjectConfiguration;
                    AddRecentFiles(name, path);
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

This works for most of the time.
However, some files don't get read to the end and i get an error that the file contains non valid XML. I used

> foundConfigurationFile.ExtractToFile();

and fount that the readed file stops at line ~800000. But this only happens inside this code. When i open the file via editor everything is there.
It looks like the zip doesnt get loaded correctly, or for that matter, completly.
Am i running in some limitations? Or is there an error in my code i don't find?

The file is saved via:

```
 using (var file = File.OpenWrite(Path.Combine(dirInfo.ToString(), fileName.ToString()) + ".pwe"))
        {
            var zip = new ZipArchive(file, ZipArchiveMode.Create);
            var configurationEntry = zip.CreateEntry(ConfigurationFileName, CompressionLevel.Optimal);
            var stream = configurationEntry.Open();
            var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ProjectConfiguration));
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(stream, CurrentConfiguration);
            stream.Close();
            zip.Dispose();
        }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248423/discussion-on-question-by-kingrazer-xml-file-from-zip-archive-is-incomplete-in-c).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

The problem was the File.OpenWrite() method.
If you try to override a file with this method it will result in a mix between the old file and the new file, if the new file is shorter than the old file.
File.OpenWrite() doenst truncate the old file first [as stated in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.openwrite?view=net-7.0)

In order to do it correctly it was neccesary to use the File.Create() method. Because this method truncates the old file first.